# Find_by_xpath results with errors

Tags: web-scraping, python-3.7

I'm Bart and I am new into Python and this is my first post here.
As a fan of whisky I wanted to scrape some shops to give me recent deals on whisky, however, I stuck with Asda's page. I browsed here for ages but without any luck hence my post.

Thank you.

Browser is opening, and closing as expected.

below is my creation:

```
Import libraries
# import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
# import pandas as pd
# import requests
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

# specify url
#url = "https://groceries.asda.com/product/whisky/glenmorangie-the-original-single-malt-scotch-whisky/68303869"
url = "https://groceries.asda.com/search/whisky/1/relevance-desc/so-false/Type%3A3612046177%3AMalt%20Whisky"

# run webdriver with headless option
options = FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
options.add_argument('--headless')
# get page
driver.get(url)
# execute script to scroll down the page
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;')
# sleep for 30s
time.sleep(30)
# close driver
driver.close()

# find element by xpath
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='componentsContainer']//*[@id='listingsContainer']//*[@class='product active']//*[@class='title productTitle']")
"""soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')"""

print('Number of results', len(results))
```

Here is the output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/asda.py", line 29, in <module>
    results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='componentsContainer']//*[@id='listingsContainer']//*[@class='product active']//*[@class='title productTitle']")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 410, in find_elements_by_xpath
    return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to stick to the way you have already written. Do not go for hardcoded delay as that is always inconsistent. Try to opt for [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). That said this is how you can get the result:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://groceries.asda.com/search/whisky"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.get(url)
item = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='co-product-list__title']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",item)
results = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'co-item')]//*[@class='co-product__title']/a")))
print('Number of results:', len(results))
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Number of results: 61
```

Comment: Thank you for above. But would you be able explain me whith more datailed walkthrough or maybe guide me where I need to dive in? Also I cannot uderstand why there is only 56 results where browser shows 131 results.

Comment: To get them all you need to traverse next pages because 56 or something the site displays in it's landing page.

Comment: Thank you, all strats to work the way I wanted :D.Can you tell me why have you used "/a" after square brackets, I cannot find explantion of that.

Comment: That `/a` after square brackets means the xpath will locate the content of `a` tag (in which title is located) in that page. Otherwise if you skipped it then the xpath locates the full block which is too broad and should error out.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, but it looks that page is too difficult for my knowledge for now lol.